# Floating label not working on input type email

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ng-animate

Hi i found the following codepen searching for a floating labels solution for Angular

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dgoncalves1/pen/XmWLEw/)

Forked it and made some modifications to my current project, but at some point found out that it's not working with `<input type="email>"` on that specific attribute. Haven't figured yet why and I'm kinda stuck on that.

It works with any other type just email it's not working

Anyone knows why this might happen?

### The Pen is not working with input type EMAIL, but does with any other type

I'll put the code below for reference.

### HTML

```
<div ng-app='myApp' class="container">
  <div class="field">
     <label ng-show="betterField" class="show-hide">Better field</label>
     <input  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="betterField" placeholder="Better field"/>
    </div>
  <div class="field">
     <label ng-show="betterField2" class="show-hide">Better select</label>
     <select  class="form-control input-sm short-input" ng-model="betterField2" />
       <option value="" disabled >Better select</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css'); 

.container {
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.show-hide.ng-hide-add, 
.show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all linear 0.2s;
    display: block!important;
    position: absolute;
}

.show-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
    top: -8px;
    display: block!important;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.show-hide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    top: -14px;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block!important;
    position: absolute;
}

.field {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.field > label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    color: #428bca;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.field > input {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0!important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-radius: 0;;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #555555;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-top: 15px
}

.short-input {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The email field label only becomes visible after typing something valid into the field. If the field is invalid the label won't show.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyPVYX

To create new fields you just need to make sure the ng-show value on the label matches the ng-model value on the input.

```
<label ng-show="betterEmailField" class="show-hide">Better Email field</label>
 <input  type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="betterEmailField" placeholder="Better Email field"/>
```

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this answer but obviously you didn't read my question properly, I'm talking about the input **type** attribute, if you change it to `email` in your pen it will not work, and it has nothing to do with the ng-show or ng-model. Try it.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, I thought I'd set the type to email. I updated my answer.